# Bottom to top navigation in Bootstrap 3 - Affix?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first question so please excuse me if it is ridiculous/rather vague.

I have been trying for days to get a navigation that starts at the bottom and then when scrolled it sticks to the to, something that is similar to [this](http://poolhousedigital.com/) website.
All I've managed to do so far is this:

```
<div id="nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="443" data-offset-bottom="200">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-affix-top navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand1" href="#why"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/228x63"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#pourquoi">Why why why ?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#comment">How How How</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#rdv">Action call</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bio">Who who who</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.navbar-nav {
font-size: 1.4em;
font-family: "adelle";
color: #fff;

}




#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index:11; }

.navbar-nav > li > a {

color: #fff;
text-align:center;



}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{

color: #59aa80;
background-color: transparent;
transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
-moz-transition: 1s;
-o-transition:1s;

}

.navbar-nav li.active:after {
content: " .";
display: block;
text-indent: -99em;
color: #fff;
height: 0px;
margin-left: -.8em;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 3px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
width: 1px;
text-align:center;}
.navbar .nav .active > a {
background-color: none;
background: 0 !important; 
color: #FFF !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
text-align:center;}


.navbar {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
text-align:center;}

.navbar-header {
padding-left: 40px; }
```

I have searched stackoverflow.com as well as JSFiddle, Bootply, Bootsnip etc without any luck so it would be much appreciated if I could get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap `affix` component to position it to the top once scrolling reaches a specific point.

Here's a working example..

http://www.bootply.com/121595