# Bootstrap navigation - from bottom to top / affix

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look on a following link:
[bootstrap nav example](http://www.glasgoweb.net/economizer/)

I want to achieve the same result in terms of navigation. So when we start browsing the web, menu in on the bottom, after scrolling down it goes top and stay there. I've read in doc's of Bootstrap that it might be connected with affix. But - its not clear to me how to achieve that. I've use such code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom affix-bottom" role="navigation" data-spy="affix">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                    <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span class="light">Start</span> Bootstrap
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

But it doesn't seems to work.. Is there any other idea how to approach it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bottom to top navigation in Bootstrap 3 - Affix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383055/bottom-to-top-navigation-in-bootstrap-3-affix)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the theme you linked, all they are doing is putting the initial content above the normal navbar.

```
<div id="home" class="flexslider">
    <!-- div stuff -->
</div>
<header class="main">
    <div class="container>
        <!-- navbar stuff -->
    </div>
</header>
```

This keeps the navbar on the bottom initially, then after you click the initial button or scroll down, the header stays at the top of the page for the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You are almost correct ! Its displaying but not in correct formats ! You have to change the style of the toggle button and set the width 100% for nav bar

```
<nav style="width:100%" class="navbar navbar-custom affix-bottom" role="navigation" data-spy="affix">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button style="background-color:lightgray" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                    <i  class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span class="light">Start</span> Bootstrap
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: I've tried that code, but unfortunatelly its not working. Could you be so kind and take a look on this layout? http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/ i dont have an idea why its not working..

Comment: In that web site what i want to see ? navbar works fine